# Multiple Lookup between tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

please guide me.
I have trouble choosing the formula for the score column.
To better understand, I took a screenshot of my work environment.
Is there a solution? 
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the logic used to populate the second table. It's not immediately clear how your tables are linked to eachother (namely the scores). How does `medal #` relate to `score`?

Comment: You are right. The previous photo was meaningless. I edited the photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly simplified version of BigBen's answer that doesn't required Dynamic Array formulas:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[#Headers],[medal 1]:[medal 4]]="medal "&Table2[medal number])*(Table1[@[medal 1]:[medal 4]]*Table2[score]))`

[image]

Comment: Good one! I deleted my answer though because the lookup table now includes `Medal ` instead of just the number.

Comment: By changing the size of the first and second tables, the medals are automatically added or subtracted. So the formula must be dynamic. I added one medal to both tables, but the range of the formula was not updated.

Comment: @BigBen It was Fixed. With the help of the OFFSET function, I made the range dynamic. Anyway, thank you for your feedback. Your guide was very complete and helped me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

SUMPRODUCT with Simple LOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table2[@[Medal 1]:[Medal 4]],LOOKUP(Table2[[#Headers],[Medal 1]:[Medal 4]],Table3[Medal],Table3[Score]))
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty much the same as mine except yours actually makes sense given the latest edit (inclusion of `Medal`) in the lookup table. Upvoted.

Comment: yes, sorry, I came in after the update and did not see yours till after I posted.

Comment: No sorry needed - it's a valid answer so happy to upvote.

Comment: Not sure why you would, is your version a different language? @m.vesali

Comment: @ScottCraner It was Fixed.thank you for your feedback.